# Issue With References Being Resolved

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I've built a project with ASP.NET using C# and the project worked perfectly fine in the VS13 environment, but when put on IIS it's been nothing but frustrating. The structure of the project utilizes MVC, and as such uses directories in the project for each the Models, Controllers, and Views.

In the Master Page, I'm calling two references:

- `TrailerWizardsPortal.Models`
- `TrailerWizardsPortal.Controllers`

**The Issue:**

When I run a page that uses the Master Page, the project breaks because of these references. Some additional information that may help one better understand:

- Framework 4.5 is used in the project and in IIS, and is installed on the server
- The Master Page front-end has been changed from CodeBehind to CodeFile
- IIS is version 8.5

**Output:**

The output is the standard "Compilation Error" that the type or namespace doesn't exist. In this case, 'Controllers' and 'Models' both are culprits.

How could I go about having IIS realize that these directories exist?

**Error:**

Server Error in '/' Application.

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Controllers' does not exist in the namespace 'TrailerWizardsPortal' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Line 7:  using System.Configuration;
Line 8:  using TrailerWizardsPortal;
Line 9:  using TrailerWizardsPortal.Controllers; ← the line that breaks
Line 10: using TrailerWizardsPortal.Models;
Line 11: using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

'Controllers' and 'Models' are both located in the location as specified by the using statements.

Comment: Can you post the actual exception you're getting?

Comment: Is it a web application project? Then don't use CodeFile, that's for Website projects only.

Comment: @Silvermind The question has been updated.

Comment: @MarkFitzpatrick, it originally was coded as CodeBehind which was the default, but that led to another issue (Parse Error) of the Master Page front end. That fix was was suggested from another thread.

Comment: What was the parser error? You should only use CodeFile if the site is a website project and codebehind if it's a web application project. When you put it on IIS did you compile it first or just copy the files over to it?

Comment: @MarkFitzpatrick I'll be able to get a more detailed answer for you tomorrow about the parser error, but essentially it didn't recognize the file type of the Master Page. The project was compiled prior to it being copied onto the wwwroot of IIS and compiled correctly. It is in fact a web application project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out my issue. I had to convert my 'Website' directory to be an application. Here's the steps I had to follow:

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Expand the site you wish to work on
3. Right-click on the 'Website' directory (this may be named something else for you - the directory which contains all your .aspx and .cs files) and choose 'Convert to Application'
4. Fill the fields accordingly to your configuration and click OK

Keep in mind this was an ASP.NET web application, so this may or may not be a resolution for you.

Seems like a rookie mistake, but that's what fixed it for me. Hope this helps someone out.